# How to run multiple tasks in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, capistrano, deployment, task

I have a Capistrano deploy.rb script which has multiple tasks that can be invoked on the command line

```
cap site1_to_live deploy
cap site2_to_live deploy
(...etc)
```

I have tried combining these into a single task as follows

```
task :all_to_live do
  site1_to_live
  site2_to_live
  site3_to_live
end
```

However, only one of the tasks is executed.  How can I get all of them to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define rake task which would group the subtasks. Run this single rake task with capistrano.

This is better because you will be also able to run this grouping task locally.